# Laravel problem store variables data in Database

Tags: php, database, laravel, variables

In my database name `files` have columns `id_message` and `file_path`. File is stored in `MyFiles/{id_message}`.

Problem is how variables `$idParameter` and `$pathFile` save in database. No errors show.

```
    function fileUpload(Request $request)
    {

    $request->validate([
        'id_message' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);
   
    $idParameter = $request->id_message=$request->id_message;

    $result=$request->file('file_path')->store('MyFiles/'.$idParameter);
    return ["result"=>$result];
    
    $pathFile = getPathname('MyFiles/'.$idParameter);

    $file = new File;
    $file->id_message=$idParameter;
    $file->file_path=$pathFile;
    $file->save();
    
}
```

Comment: Can you post your migrations? Are the attributes fillable?

Comment: you are returning in the middle of your code. after the return nothing will be executed. so there will be no db entry.

Comment: Can you share more details? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `return ["result"=>$result];` and add this into end.